# imbedded if statement not working properly

Tags: python, authentication

his is my first time using this website, so i dont know how to use it properly... apologies if its difficult to read.
i have some code to make a login system for my project, and i have used if and else statements to let the user to log in. however, while it works as in there are no error messages its not doing what i would like it to do. when the user login is, it asks them for the username:

```
username = input("Enter login name: ")
    if username in Users:
            
            passw = input("Enter password: ")
            if passw in Users: 
                print ("Login successful!")
```

however if the username is correct, the program moves onto " passw = input("Enter password: ") " but no matter if the password is correct or not, it goes back to the login menu... im not sure how to fix it.

#full code:

```
global number
global Users
global username


number = 1
Users = {}
status = ""

def newuser():
    global number
    print('To create your unique username, please answer these few questions: ')
    first = input('Please type your first name: ')
    second = input('Please type your surname/last name: ')
    year = input('Please type your birth year: ')
    
    part1 = (first[:3])
    part2 = (second[:3])
    part3 = (year[2:])
    username = part1 + part2 + part3
    
    
    username = str(part1[:3] + part2[:3] + part3[:2] + '' + str(number))
    number = number + 1
    print('')
    print ('here is your unique username: ')
    print (username)
    print('')
    print ('Make sure you know your username for when you login in next time!')
    passw = input('please type in your password to login to your account with: ')
    Users[username] = passw
    print('')
    print ('Your account is made! Taking you back to the menu... ')
    print('')

def olduser():
    global username
    global passw
    global Users
    username = input("Enter login name: ")
    if username in Users:
            print (Users)
            passw = input("Enter password: ")
            if passw in Users: 
                print ("Login successful!") 
                mainmenu()
    else:
            print("User doesn't exist!")
    

def mainmenu():
    print('test for main menu is ready')

while status != "q":
    status = input("Are you a registered user? y/n? Press q to quit: ") 

    if status == "n": 
        newuser()          
    elif status == "y": 
        olduser()
    else:
        print('invalid input try again')
```

Comment: You are checking `if passw in Users:` but the keys in the `Users` dictionary are usernames, not password. You have to check `if passw == Users[username]` to see if the password is correct.

Comment: Also please note that storing passwords in plain text is very weak security, check if the framework you are using offers some login utitlities and use those. Generally speaking, do not implement your own security library, but use a well trusted one.

Comment: ah thank you! it works now : )